# How to set different events for dynamically created element

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Im trying to create event with different index for dynamically created GroupBox. With my actual code event for every groupbox is that same. How can i make event with different index for every groupbox? My Code:

```
public void LoadGry()
        {

           // GroupBox groupbox = new GroupBox();
            Label nazwagry = new Label();
            for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                GroupBox groupbox = new GroupBox();
                groupbox.Text = myCollection[i];
                groupbox.Size = new Size(290, 131);
                groupbox.Location = new Point(6, 150 * (myCollection.Count - i - 1));
                groupbox.ForeColor = Color.White;
                Label label1 = new Label();
                label1.Text = groupbox.Text;
                label1.AutoSize = true;
                label1.Location = new Point(groupbox.Location.X + 80, groupbox.Location.Y + 20);
                groupbox.Controls.Add(label1);
                Gry.Controls.Add(label1);

                PictureBox picturebox = new PictureBox();
                picturebox.Location = new Point(groupbox.Location.X + 5, groupbox.Location.Y + 20);
                picturebox.Size = new Size(75, 75);
                picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                picturebox.LoadAsync(myCollection3[i]);
                groupbox.Click += new EventHandler(delegate {groupboxclick(groupbox, picturebox, i);});
                Label label2 = new Label();
                label2.Text = "Status: " + "Aktualny";
                label2.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                label2.AutoSize = true;
                label2.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X, label1.Location.Y + 20);
                Gry.Controls.Add(label2);
                Label zapiszopis = new Label();
                zapiszopis.Text = myCollection4[i];
                zapiszopis.Visible = false;

                Gry.Controls.Add((Control)groupbox);    

                //MessageBox.Show("pokaz mi wysokosc");
                }
            }
private void groupboxclick(GroupBox groupbox, PictureBox picturebox, int itest)
        {


            groupbox.ForeColor = Color.Aqua;
            this.pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = picturebox.BackgroundImage;
            opishacka.Text = myCollection4[itest];
        }
```

Comment: Why You want different handlers ?Can't You just provide sender attribute to this eventhandler so You will be able to easly retrieve GroupBox which fired the event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the event setup is using the variable K value. For use the number instead you probably needs to create an expression manually to use the current value in each case.

BUT
You can easily do what you want using the following properties to attach values to controls.

1-) Tag in WinForms & WPF:

```
// Setup
pictureBox.Tag = i;

// Event
int i = (int) pictureBox.Tag;
```

2-) ViewState in WebForms

```
// Setup
ViewState[pictureBox.UniqueID] = i;

// Event
int i = (int) ViewState[pictureBox.UniqueID];
```

You can use many other techniques. I only post one for each popular framework. I guest that you are in a WinFors project.

Hope this help!